# Prove that the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]\over (x^2,y^3,z^7)$ is Artin.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, artinian

I was trying to show that given a maximal ideal, every decreasing chain terminates. So, I found a maximal ideal $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]\over (x^2,y^3,z^7)$ and proved it is maximal. Also, any decreasing chain from $(x,y,z)$ should terminate. But, I have no idea with how to prove it for the whole maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]\over (x^2,y^3,z^7)$. I think there must be a nice way.

Comment: As far as I can see this quotient ring has only one maximal ideal, so I don't get what you mean by "*the whole maximal ideals*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ring $\Bbb Q[x,y,z]/(x^a,y^b,z^c)$ is finite dimensional over as
a vector space $\Bbb Q$, so every descending chain of vector subspaces
stabilises (in particular every descending chain of ideals stabilises).
As a vector space it has dimension $abc$ and a basis consists of $x^i y^j z^k$ where $0\le i<a$, $0\le j<b$, $0\le k<c$.

Comment: That is so a nice perspective! I think you are considering that there is one to one correspondence between subspaces in the vector space and ideals in the given ring. Is it trivial? I mean $\mathbb{Q}$ acts on a subspace, but ideals are not.

Comment: Oh no I'm not: every ideal corresponds to a vector subspace but not vice versa.

Comment: Oh then it is clear! Also I have one more question. It seems true that a quotient of multivariate(not infinite) polynomial ring over a field $F$ by a finitely generated ideal is a finite dimensional over $F$. Is that right?

Comment: No: $F[X,Y]/(XY)$ is not finite dimensional over $F$.

Comment: Right! Thank you for your helps!

Answer (score 1):

$\{x^iy^jz^k\mid 0\leq i\leq 1, 0\leq j\leq 2,0\leq k\leq 6\}$ is a $\mathbb Q$ basis, so it is a finite dimensional $\mathbb Q$ vector space, which is of course, Artinian.